# Windows server 2008 File Server problems

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, file-server

First of all i would like to apolagies for my lack of knowladge in this matter but with your help i hope i can fix the problem.

Here's the situation:
We have a Windows 2008R2 Server running Databases, File Server, DNS Server and AD controller (I know it is not best pratice, but it's what we got)

Recently, and without any changes in server configuration, some people are having problems accessing their shared folders on the server. When they try to access it says access denied (even when logging on with domain credentials), but what is most weird is that without any changes from my side, people are suddenly allowed to access the folders and after X time the problem returns.... And so on.

I already tried clear all conections with `net use *\delete`, and I also removed Stored User Names and Passwords (Control Panel\User Acconts\Advanced) but nothing works.

Some times when i try to enter the server address `\\192.168.2.100` or `\\Umclinica` it open the window to enter my credencials and when i try to put the domain credencials for that user it says:

> "Logon Unsuccessful: The user name you typed is the same as the user name you logged in with. That user name has already been tried. A domain controller cannot be found to verify that user name."

Another wierd thing i noticed is that until now it only happened on windows XP.

Do u think this might be a Server problem or local PC problem ? I already search all over the place but couldnt figure out the problem.

Beside this problem the server is running as normal, databases are working good, internet (even in the problematic PCs), softwares, etc... everything fine but file server.

Comment: Domain name confusion. What are the windows xp machines using for dns

Comment: If it's only XP clients, the solution is simple: Replace them with a OS that is not out of support since 2014.

Comment: My XP machines run fine, so that's not it.

Comment: @deemeetree: The DNS was always the same for all machines in our network, 192.168.2.100 (Server IP) following by openDNS 208.67.220.220/208.67.222.222 Sven: Thats the best solution not only for this problem, unfortenly our company dont have enough resources to make those changes which include buying software but also new machines. Anyways, i will try flush DNS in all machine and see how it goes, Thanks for the tip deemeetree.

Answer (score -2):

Seems editing the host file on each machine worked.

But i still have no clue why that happened when everything was working just fine.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The root cause of the problem is that you have OpenDNS servers on the client machines. Your clients are asking OpenDNS for the address of your server, which it doesn't konw. Your server should have the OpenDNS servers set as forwarders, and your client machines should only have AD DNS servers configured. The reason the host file fixes this problem is that host file resolution occurs first, before DNS servers are queried.

Comment: I appreciate your coment Longneck but it seems thats not the problem. I have other site working this way with client machine using server IP as primary DNS and openDNS alternative.
I sayed the problem was solved with host file but it seems it only worked out for some clients, i still have some machines with the problem.

Comment: One more thing i found. The PC's wiith this problem cant logon RDP server with local IP (192.168.1.xxxx or with servidor) but can with internet IP.

Machines that dont have this problem can log into RDP normally with internal IP or Server name.

Comment: Sounds like you have a routing issue. What is the default gateway on all of these machines?

Comment: Heres an example:
IP: 192.168.2.120 | 
Mask: 255.255.255.0 | 
Default Gateway: 192.168.2.254 (router) | 
DNS: 192.168.2.100 (Server IP) | 
Alternative DNS: 208.67.220.220 (opendns)

Comment: Server configurations: 192.168.2.100 Mask 255.255.255.0 DefaultGateway: 192.168.2.254 | DNS: 127.0.0.1 | Alternative DNS: empty